# DataGrid & Mouse Event as parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding, mouseevent

Trying to program drag and drop of text files from a WPF DataGrid to notepad/excel. 
I am trying to use this code in MainViewModel:

```
    private void FileDragDrop(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Process.Start(Path.Combine(ResultSnapshotFolder, cell));
            if (e.MiddleButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;
            var d = new DataObject();
            d.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, SelectedRow);
            d.SetData(DataFormats.Text, SelectedRow.ToString());
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(grid, d, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

XAML mousebinding:

```
     <MouseBinding
                MouseAction="MiddleClick"
                Command="{Binding FileDragDrop}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FileGrid }" />
```

Below is the overloaded DelegateCommand, for different mouse actions:

```
     public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter, MouseEventArgs argsMouse)
    {
        _dataGridDragDrop(parameter, argsMouse);
    }
```

My problem is that "Execute(object parameter)" is always executed at runtime, as if, the "MouseEventArgs argsMouse" is never passed from the XAML view to the MainViewModel with the DataGrid object.

Basically I am only able to run methods with 1 parameter when I want to run a method with 2 parameters.

Does anyone know a way around this or a different approach that may overcome the issue?

Comment: You can add more parameters using a MultiBinding Converter, otherwise you need to implement an AttachedBehavior

Comment: `ICommand` has no `Execute(object, MouseEventArgs)` method. `MouseBinding` has an `ICommand`. It calls the `Execute(object)` method that `ICommand` has. It's not as smart as you hoped.

Comment: I'd say it's because MouseEventArgs is not a ViewModel object: it belongs to the View

Comment: Just handle the drop event with a regular event handler, and Execute the Command from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the information which mouse button is pressed then you don't need the `MouseEventArgs`.

Just change

```
if (e.MiddleButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;
```

to

```
if (Mouse.MiddleButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;
```

and you should be good to go.

In fact nearly all properties and methods that are exposed by `MouseEventArgs` are also exposed by the static class `Mouse`.

Comment: But all this should be already superseded by `MouseAction="MiddleClick"`

Comment: @MachineLearning Yes, it absolutely should. But it's certainly possible that the `FileDragDrop` method is called from other mouse-related events as well.

Comment: Thanks haindl this solved my issue, thanks to all others who responded also.

Comment: @contraflow You're very welcome. If you are happy with my answer then I would be happy if you could mark it as the accepted answer.  :-)